# Order of the labels in geom_col wrong, although the factor levels are set correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a likert/diverging barplot in ggplot2. Although I set the order of the levels using the factor levels, the order in the barplot is not correct (I use geom_col), in the legend the order is correct.

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Reporducible expample:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

data = data.table::data.table(code = paste0("A", c(1,2,4,5)), 
         label = c("Very good", "Good", "Not good", "Bad"),
         pct = c(9.6, 66, -22.7, -1.7),
         group = 1)
data$label <- factor(data$label, levels = unique(data[order(code)]$label))

ggplot(data, aes(x = group, y = pct, group = label, fill = label)) +
  geom_col(width = 0.8, position = position_stack()) +
  coord_flip()
```

In the plot the level "bad" comes before "not good", as supposed to the other way around.

Comment: It's because of negative values, it actually comes after if you think about it.

Answer (score 0):

The plot is technically correct. Negative values stacked 'on top' of other negative values stack to the left. The easiest way round this is simply to re-level your factors appropriately to account for this. You would then need to specify the `limits` inside `scale_fill_*` to rearrange the legend appropriately.

Note that you don't need `coord_flip` now, since `geom_col` has an `orientation` argument. This allows for nicer scaling of your bars so that they look more like actual bars:

```r
data$label <- factor(data$label, c('Very good', 'Good', 'Bad', 'Not good'))

ggplot(data, aes(y = group, x = pct, group = label, fill = label)) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack(), col = 'gray50', orientation = 'y') +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = 2) +
  coord_fixed(20) +
  labs(x = 'Percent', y = 'Group') +
  scale_fill_brewer(limits =  c('Very good', 'Good', 'Not good', 'Bad')) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

If this feels wrong to you, then you can do it all in ggplot, since one alternative is to plot all the values as positive values, then fake the axis.

```r
ggplot(data, aes(y = factor(group), x = abs(pct), group = label, fill = label)) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack(), col = 'gray50', orientation = 'y') +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = ~.x + sum(data$pct[data$pct < 0]),
                     breaks = 0:5 * 25 - 25 - sum(data$pct[data$pct < 0])) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = -sum(data$pct[data$pct < 0]), linetype = 2) +
  coord_fixed(20) +
  labs(x = 'Percent', y = 'Group') +
  scale_fill_brewer() +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]